# Why are `colMeans()` and `rowMeans()` functions faster than using the mean function with `lapply()`?

Tags: performance, r, mean

What I want to ask is, algorithmically, what do the `rowMeans()` and `colMeans()` functions do to optimize speed?

Comment: I don't think it's algorithmic, I think it's a matter of what can be coded directly in C and what has to go through the R interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

In addition, consider what `lapply()` does. It sets up repeated calls to the function `mean()`. So as well as the overhead of actually computing a mean (which is done in fast C code), the `lapply()` version repeatedly incurs the overhead of the sanity checking code and method dispatch associated with `mean()`.

`rowMeans()` and `colMeans()` incur only a single set of sanity checks as internally, their C code is optimised to loop over the rows/columns there rather than via separate R calls.

Answer (score 4):

`rowMeans` and `colMeans` are faster than because they call C code directly, rather than being interpreted by the R interpreter.

Comment: Is there a difference in speed/efficiency between ``rowMeans`` and ``colMeans``? Thanks. (looked at various questions on so, but couldn't find it mentioned, did I miss a related post on this?)