# how do i perform ks test on multiple columns in a matrix?

Tags: r

(a) Generate 1000 samples where each consists of 50 independent exponential random variables with
mean 1. Estimate the mean of each sample. Draw a histogram of the means.
(b) Perform a KS test on each sample against the null hypothesis that they are from an exponential
random variable with a mean that matches the mean of the data set. Draw a histogram of the
1000 values of D.

i did part a with this code

```
set.seed(0)
simdata = rexp(50000, 1)
matrixdata = matrix(simdata,nrow=50,ncol=1000)
means.exp = apply(matrixdata,2,mean)
means.exp
hist(means.exp)
```

but im stuck on part (b)

Comment: What about part (b) are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` on the column indices:

```
# KS test on every column
# H0: pexp(rate = 1/mean(column))
lst.ks <- lapply(1:ncol(matrixdata), function(i)
    ks.test(matrixdata[, i], "pexp", 1.0/means.exp[i]))
```

Or directly without having to rely on `means.exp`:

```
lst.ks <- lapply(1:ncol(matrixdata), function(i)
    ks.test(matrixdata[, i], "pexp", 1.0/mean(matrixdata[, i])))
```

Here `1.0/means.exp[i]` corresponds to the rate of the exponential distribution.

PS. Using `means.exp = colMeans(matrixdata)` is faster than `apply(matrixdata, 2, mean)`, see e.g. [here for a relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759937/why-are-colmeans-and-rowmeans-functions-faster-than-using-the-mean-funct).

---

To extract the test statistic and store it in a vector simply `sapply` over the KS test results:

```
# Extract test statistic as vector
Dstat <- sapply(lst.ks, function(x) x$statistic);

# (gg)plot Dstat
ggplot(data.frame(D = Dstat), aes(D)) + geom_histogram(bins = 30);
```

[image]

Comment: how would I just get the D statistic so i can draw a histogram with them?

Comment: @PeterTan Please take a look at my updated my solution.

Comment: @PeterTan If this answers your question, please consider closing the question by accepting the answer.